# .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) deprecated in GooglePlayServices 8.4

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I was going through Udacity course on integrating Google Sign-In into Android app. In that we try to get the current user's details via .getCurrentOerson() in the onConnected(), but the .getCurrentOerson() has been deprecated.

```
 public class SignInAct extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Button signIn,signOut,revoke;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signinlay);
    mGoogleApiClient = buildApiClient();
}
GoogleApiClient buildApiClient(){
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
            addConnectionCallbacks(this).
            addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
            addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()).
            addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE)).build();
}

    @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    signIn.setEnabled(false);
    signOut.setEnabled(true);
    revoke.setEnabled(true);

    Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

}}
```

Whats the way to get the displayName now?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`public abstract Person getCurrentPerson (GoogleApiClient googleApiClient)` documentation:](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html#getCurrentPerson%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29)

> This method is deprecated.
>
> If you are using People Api simply for signing in and fetching identity, please use [GoogleSignInApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html) instead.

[From the `GoogleSignInResult` documentation:](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInResult)

> `public GoogleSignInAccount getSignInAccount()`
>
> Returns a `GoogleSignInAccount` reflecting the user's sign in information if sign-in completed successfully; or null when failed.

[From the `GoogleSignInAccount` documentation:](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#getDisplayName%28%29)

> `public String getDisplayName()`
>
> Returns the display name of the signed in user if you built your configuration starting from new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)} or with requestProfile() configured; null otherwise. Not guaranteed to be present for all users, even when configured.

Comment: thank you for sharing the solution, the app is compiling but it doesn't sign in. Please have a look at this pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/x6WdSeVA) and guide me where i could be going wrong. I keep getting this output when i click SignIn button - 01-23 18:41:50.914 22617-22617/com.authorwjf D/SignInActivity: handleSignInResult:false. I have included the json configuration file also added the oauth client id into my string values xml.